# how do i place items in css3?

Tags: html, css

i'm coding a web by using only html and css and i'm having a problem with placing div tags in css
this is the output i want to make : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCMjw.jpg)

the problem is i cant place these items in their place in the image.
this is my code :

```css
body{
 background-color: red;
}
#container{
   background-image: url(http://uupload.ir/files/16md_background.jpg);
   width: 1366px;
 height: 768px;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
 border-radius: 2px;
}
#header{
 background-image: url(http://uupload.ir/files/8sr2_header.png);
 width:1366px;
 height:77px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 22px;
 left: 170px;

}

#webdesign{
 background-image: url(http://uupload.ir/files/k11n_untitled-1.png);
 width: 308px;
 height: 308px;
}
#bannerdeisgn{
 background-image: url(http://uupload.ir/files/k11n_untitled-1.png);
 width: 308px;
 height: 308px;
}
#logodesign{
 background-image: url(http://uupload.ir/files/k11n_untitled-1.png);
 width: 308px;
 height: 308px;
}
#carddesign{
 background-image: url(http://uupload.ir/files/k11n_untitled-1.png);
 width: 308px;
 height: 308px;
}
#nav li{
 list-style-type: none;
 position: absolute;

}
#home{
 background-image: url(http://uupload.ir/files/orek_home.png);
 width:32px;
 height:35px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 100px;
}
#home {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
}
#home:hover, #home:focus, #home:active {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
#footer{
 background-image: url(http://uupload.ir/files/ywc_footer.png);
 width: 1366px;
 height: 77px;
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 712px;
 left: 170px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <!---\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/////////////////////////////-->
 <!---\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/////////////////////////////-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="bg"></div>
<ul id="nav">
 <a href="#"><li id="bannerdeisgn"></li></a>
 <a href="#"><li id="logodesign"></li></a>
 <a href="#"><li id="carddesign"></li></a>
 <a href="#"><li id="webdesign"></li></a>
</ul>
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block` to li and remove `position: absolute`

```
#nav li{
    list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  border-radius:200px
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o39c5nr9/)**

---

Though it is not advisable to help in blind way, here it is **[Demo 2 Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/o39c5nr9/3/)**

Comment: thanks, what about the others?

Comment: others?? Do you want entire page to be developed here?

Comment: no no ,my Question is that when i give a tag a position the other elements move from their Current position , what should i do?

Comment: there is no need of absolute positioning here. why are you even using it.

Comment: this is another problem for ex. when i remove the "position: absolute" from  "#nav li" the li goes behind the background image...

Comment: when u use absolute position, it should have relative parent element. Read through [this link](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) for better understanding.

Comment: that is Exactly my problem the whole positioning in css and i've read many Articles but ... thanks again